# DELETE FROM X WHERE IN (..) is not deleting rows

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where I'm filtering a table by a bunch of different values. There's about 30 different filters on this table and since I'm still a novice with MySQL I have it done in a `stored procedure` executing multiple `DELETE` queries from a temporary table to filter. This example is only going to show the filter that I'm having issues from, which is a `DELETE FROM table WHERE value IN ()` query.

Here's a test Schisma:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE blocked (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    other_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO accounts (name) VALUES ('Chris'), ('Andy');
INSERT INTO blocked  (user_id, other_id) VALUES (1, 2);
```

The queries create two tables: the accounts table containing two rows, and the blocked table containing one row where `user_id` 1 has `user_id` 2 blocked.

Here's the query that's causing us some problem (Please note that the queries are actually more complex than displayed, but the DELETE query is 100% the same, and the issue persists through the test example provided):

```
BEGIN
    #user_in input is a int(11) value bassed in the CALL FUNCTION(ID).

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filtered AS (SELECT * FROM accounts);

    DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id IN (SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.user_id = user_in);

    SELECT * FROM filtered;
END
```

This query should delete the row with the `user_id` field of 2, as  in the blocked table the only row is `(1, 2)`.

Running the SELECT query directly providing the user_id returns the other_id of 2.

```
SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.other_id = 2;
```

However, the stored procedure returns both rows, instead of just one. Why?

NOTE: The above query is to show what is returned when the query `SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.user_id = user_in`, another example would be `SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.user_id = 1` granted `user_in` is set to 1. Both of these queries will return a set of `(2)` which would make the delete query look like `DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id IN (2)`. This is not working, for whatever reason.

Comment: "I have it done in a stored procedure"...because...?

Comment: @Strawberry `and since I'm still a novice with MySQL I have it done in a stored procedure` as-well as `There's about 30 different filters on this table` and the stored procedure is actually slightly over 250 lines long. The complexity of the SELECT query to get the same results is far above my level.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand why you need the filtered table.

Comment: @Strawberry It's probably not `needed` and the result can be achieved with a single complex SELECT query. I just do not have the knowledge to write such an advanced select query, so creating a table, then filtering using a bunch of smaller/simple DELETE queries is easier for myself.

Comment: I appreciate that the problem may in reality be more complicated than you have indicated above, but what you've outlined above is really easy; it's just a join. For more help with that, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

To get a simple select of that users use next query

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accounts.user_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct blocked.other_id from blocked)
```

To do it with one single select without deleting rows from temporary table use next query:

```
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filtered AS (SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accounts.user_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct blocked.other_id from blocked));
    SELECT * from filtered;
END
```

No need for select all in temporary table first and then delete specific rows.

Hope it helps

EDIT:

I'v read the question and still a bit confused about you problem. But i checked this solution and it works perfectly so i don't understand what is problem with this. In  your procedure you have

```
DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id IN (SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.user_id = user_in);
```

and after that you say that

```
SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.other_id = 2;
```

And i can say that `blocked.other_id` and `blocked.user_id` are two different columns.

No disrespect but amateur mistake to mix up columns. :)

Comment: Please read the question, "There's about 30 different filters on this table" so issuing a single SELECT statement isn't going to cut it. The store procedure I have is over 250 lines, and I'm asking for help with the single filter issue I have.

Comment: Oops! I changed the `DELETE` query to reflect the `user_in` field, but forgot to change the returning query to the appropriate example! Either way the result from the query would still be a set containing `(2)` which is not being delete from my table. `(Where user_id = 2)` in this event.  Perhaps it's a MySQL version error. I'll try updating and executing the query again.

Comment: I added an explanation of why I had that SELECT query in the question. Btw. :).

Comment: Ok, i got it now. Did you solved your problem or you have still problems with proper solution?

Comment: I'll be doing another test when my servers come back from maintenance, however I'm fairly sure the code you provided in your edit is the exact code I have in effect.

Comment: And did it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with this statement:

```
DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id IN (SELECT other_id FROM blocked WHERE blocked.other_id = user_id);
```

Try changing it to this:

```
DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id 
IN (SELECT other_id FROM blocked);
```

Reason being that the `blocked` table has both a `other_id` and a `user_id` column. So where you are attempting to join out to the `filtered` table you are in fact comparing the `other_id` and `user_id` columns in the `blocked` table only. Which are not equal. So no delete happens.

Comment: One more addition to optimize whole thing is to add `DISTINCT` inside select of blocked id's so then that statement should look like `DELETE FROM filtered WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT other_id FROM blocked);`

Comment: Tom, this problem with this is that if `user_id` 1 has user_id 2 blocked. Then `2` would be in the `other_id` field. Therefor even though user_id 3 doesn't have user_id 2 blocked, he will still be filtered out, because user_id 1 does. This is where the `WHERE` statement comes into play.

Comment: @Tom Mac, There was an error in my question which I had resolved, where `user_id` was supposed to be `user_in`. I apologize, please take another look at the `DELETE` query to see the change. The goal is to only return values for the provided user_id's blocked fields.